# Internal Implementation of Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I recently started learning JS, main reason - want to learn node and related frameworks.
I have started doing some basic tutorials from freecodecamp and referring the docs from [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

I have started with ES6 constructor functions and stuck with something. Below is the details:

```js
class Book {
  constructor(author) {
    this._author = author;
  }
  // getter
  get writer() {
    return this._author;
  }
  // setter
  set writer(updatedAuthor) {
    this._author = updatedAuthor;
  }
}
```

The invocation of getter and setter is weird, coming from Java, but its okay. Adapt !!

```js
const ALEPH = new Book("Paulo Coelho");
let writtenBy = ALEPH.writer;
ALEPH.writer = "So we changing Authors now !!"
```

The above code(*syntax*) makes sense when thinking in terms of :

```
const person = {
  name: "Taylor",
  sayHello() {
    return `Hello! My name is ${this.name}.`;
  }
};
```

And that class is not a real class form OOP concepts, but a template for something called - constructor functions.

> It should be noted that the class syntax is just syntax, and not a full-fledged class-based implementation of an object-oriented paradigm, unlike in languages such as Java, Python, Ruby, etc.

This makes sense, how the getters and setters are being called as they are nothing but keys/attributes of the object holding a function against it.

**Please correct me if my understanding is wrong or I need to be more technically correct**

The question is, I have looking over the internet what the `get` and `set` keyword does internally.
I have found implementations and how to use them, not what they doing internally.

- If you can refer me to any docs which talks about what it does internally.

With **Java**, I can easily refer the internal implementation or in case of a keyword, look up the Java Spec or JVM spec to understand what is happening under the hood. I am looking for something similar for JS. Would be good to have a reference to such official docs.

Question:

1. How are the get and set keyword implemented internally?
2. Any **official docs** for JS like we have for Python or Java.

Thanks.

Comment: The best I think you could get is the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/. Hope this helps

Comment: It would be better if you skip `ES6 features` until you gain insights of **JavaScript** and it's features.

Comment: Both are object-based languages but Java is class-based while JavaScript is prototype-based. The `class` keyword is mere syntax sugar and you could be doing the same exact things without it (try https://babeljs.io with ES2015 preset). However it's unclear whether you're asking about the C/C++ source code in Node.js or Rhino runtimes or just about ECMAScript specs.

Comment: Not sure, where I asked for a recommendation for a book, blog, when I clearly mentioned I am looking for - official docs !!!

Anyways I have updated the question, since now I know the place I need to go to see how the ES6 syntax is getting converted to ES5 syntax under the hood. And others have already provided some great links, which I already liked. So keeping the question closed. But I still don't feel I asked for recommendation!   :) Thanks folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get distracted by the `ES6` features (`class`, `extends` etc...). There is nothing like `class` or `class based inheritance` in `JavaScript`. They are just **syntactical sugar** on native JavaScript **function**. The `functions` are the first class objects in JavaScript.

For example the **Book** class above will be converted as below in `ES5` using [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/en/repl)

```
"use strict";

function _instanceof(left, right) { if (right != null && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && right[Symbol.hasInstance]) { return !!right[Symbol.hasInstance](left); } else { return left instanceof right; } }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!_instanceof(instance, Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }

function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }

var Book = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function Book(author) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Book);

    this._author = author;
  } // getter


  _createClass(Book, [{
    key: "writer",
    get: function get() {
      return this._author;
    } // setter
    ,
    set: function set(updatedAuthor) {
      this._author = updatedAuthor;
    }
  }]);

  return Book;
}();
```

See how `get` and `set` are converted in `ES5`.

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) are good enough to get insights of `JavaScript` and it's features.

**Final words**: Try to avoid comparing `Java` and `JavaScript`. Learn it as something **new**.

Comment: Thanks for the babel link. It helped understand what is going behind the scene. I was under the impression these keywords are features, but in reality, it is just a way to make my life easier. But under the hood it gets interpreted as es5 native js. Thanks for links

Comment: And the reason why I compare languages to learn is because I feel the paradigm and ways can be different. But in the end, you still do the same things like - computation, define an object - mem allocation, things like these. Since I can compare things like this, it is more easy for me to understand how it is different and how things are working in that language

Comment: I didn't mean not to compare things at all. I do learn by comparing. But we no need seach for the same feature in one language to be present in another in same manner. Pardon me if interpretted wrongly. Good that the answer helped you to understand better. Good luck 

Comment: Ah ! Communication gap, haha. Nah, I am not looking for a specific feature in JS or Java. The thing is the babel now made me realise how lamda function is nothing but a Syntax for Java, there is nothing we do now that could not be done without lamdas, things are similar with ES5 and 6. But the syntax sugar opened up doors for complex computations and techniques in a nice way

Answer (score 1):

You're great!

you've noticed these things about JS and it's True, JS Classes are not real classes, JS has OLOO (object linked to other objects) so we have just the plain object, not any real class, which lead us to the behavior delegation pattern which is simpler and easier than OOP and better suits JS.

I think the internals can be found in EcmaScript 262 standards [check it here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver)

And I also would love to mention a great JS book series that take you in real depth called YDKJS and here's the link about [getters and setters](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md#getters--setters)